# sorting gridview in asp.net after refresh

Tags: vb.net, sorting, refresh, dopostback

I have a grid created using a sql datasource in my asp page. So Sorting is done automatically using asp.net in build control(no codes added for sorting in vb.net).

But If I refresh the page  or if I go to some other page, the sorting order disappears.

Is there a way to catch the previous sort order (sort direction and sort expression)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page `PreRender` event store the current values of `GridView.SortDirection` and `GridView.SortExpression` properties in, for example, `Session`:

```
this.Session[this.GetType().FullName + ".GridView.SortDirection"] = this.GridView.SortDirection;
this.Session[this.GetType().FullName + ".GridView.SortExpression"] = this.GridView.SortExpression;
```

On page `Init` event execute this code:

```
if (!this.IsPostBack && this.Session.Contains(this.GetType.FullName + ".GridView.SortDirection"))
{
    this.GridView.SortDirection = (SortDirection)this.Session[this.GetType().FullName + ".GridView.SortDirection"];
    this.GridView.SortExpression = (string)this.Session[this.GetType().FullName + ".GridView.SortExpression"];
}
```

Comment: if you need help converting this code to VB.NET, let us know.